# Is it possible to solve the longest common subsequence using Suffix Tree?

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to solve the longest common subsequence using Suffix Tree?

I am trying to work out if a longest common subsequence can be solved using a suffix tree?

Comment: Consider the specific case of ABA and ABB.  Would you be able to derive "AB" from the suffixes of each?

Answer (score 0):

A Suffix Tree is used to find the longest common prefix, which is the lowest common ancestor in a Suffix Tree.  The only time you need a data structure to find the longest common subsequence of two strings is when you implement a dynamic programming solution, which uses a 2D array to keep track of the resuls as you solve the problem.

Comment: Thank You, so I can use the suffix tree lcs, right ?

Comment: No. A sufffix tree won't give you LCS.

Comment: LCS meaning longest common subsequence.

Comment: You can: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-tree-application-5-longest-common-substring-2/